# click function on checkbox in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Click function in IE behave strange. When u click check box multiple times it's not checked or unchecked sometimes but click function do trigger. I have tested it on IE8 also, in IE8 when u click it multiple times, it does not get checked or unchecked but click function run only when check box complete action itself. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fvC5/)

**note**: This bug doesnot produce in IE10 version.

```
$('#chk').click(function(){
    $('.frm').toggleClass('green blk');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `change` event on the checkbox in place of `click` to avoid this.

```
$('#chk').change(function(){
    $('.frm').toggleClass('green blk');
});
```

Would prefer to use `.change` upon `.bind(change)`  as suggested by @user1671639

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/9fvC5/8/

Comment: Sure take your time :)

Comment: Most welcome. If this solves your problem, you can choose this as your correct answer, so that it does not appear under unanswered list :)

Comment: @AshisKumar I would like you to take a look at this answer about [bind vs on](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15658266/1671639)

Comment: Thanks @user1671639, i updated my code. Used `.change` to use its best case based upon the jQuery version used :)

Answer (score 2):

For radio button and check boxes it is better to use [**`change`**](http://api.jquery.com/change/) events using [**`.on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler attachment.

```
$('#chk').on('change', function(){
 $('.frm').toggleClass('green blk');
})
```

Here your [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9fvC5/6/)