# which is the correct way to bind event to an element

Tags: jquery, performance, event-binding

i read that events can be binded to an element as

```
$('btn-submit').bind('click', function(){
  // your custom code
});
```

and in another way as,

```
$(document).on('click', 'btn-submit', function(){
  // your custom code
});
```

which is the correct and most efficient way? I am using rails 3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery use of bind vs on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658231/jquery-use-of-bind-vs-on-click)  *there's no reason to use bind, as this function only calls the more flexible on function without even being shorter* `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit: True, but it would still call `.on` in a different way, not as event delegation. I'd say this question is rather about when to use event delegation and when to use direct event binding.

Comment: Maybe this helps to understand the purpose of event delegation: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ (then you can decide which one to choose).

Comment: @FelixKling ola bruvoo `:)` if you put it that way `:)` agreed!

Comment: Using event delegation on $(document) is likely not better for anybody - constrain the top parent as much as feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is using to bind event that are present in DOM at the time of binding and is called **Direct Binding** whereas second one is **Event Delegation** is required when elements are not present at the time of binding event but added later on.

> #### Direct and delegated events
>
> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/)