# Bind click to images loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I've been having some trouble with this block of code, and I think I've finally narrowed the problem down.    Here's the jQuery function...

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#formattingSection').load ('formattingdoc.html #formatting');

    $('#loadFormatting').click(function() {
        $('#formattingSection').load ('formattingdoc.html #formatting');
    });

    $('#loadSmileys').click(function() {
        $('#formattingSection').load ('formattingdoc.html #smileys');
    });     

    $('#formattingSection div img').click(function() {
        var code = $(this).attr("title");
        alert (code);
        $('wallpost').val($('wallpost').val() + code);
    });
});
```

Basically, it works like this.   The page loads, we load part of a doc via AJAX.   There are four buttons on the page, each one loads a new section via AJAX.   When you click #loadSmileys, it will load via AJAX several images and display them in the DIV.

I'm binding a click() event to those images...  but what I've found is that since the images aren't on the page at load time, the click event never gets bound.   When I strip all the code away and load the images without AJAX, the click binds okay.

So...  my question here...  is there a way to bind the click event to the images AFTER they are loaded via AJAX?

For reference...  I did make a jsBin [HERE](http://jsbin.com/iFitaZo/1/edit), but it's basically just hard coding the images to that I can see it works without the AJAX stuff going on.

Comment: You can use the ajax callback to rebind the handlers, or (the better method) use event delegation with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#formattingSection").on("click","div img",function() {
        var code = $(this).attr("title");
        alert (code);
        $('wallpost').val($('wallpost').val() + code);
    });
```

As `$.on` attaches event handler to the parent and all events from children are delegated to the parent

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Works great!  Just what I needed... much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you totally can attach event handles to DOM nodes loaded on-the-fly. The trick is to use jQuery.get instead of .load. .get allows you to add an additional callback function that gets executed upon AJAX completion - the perfect place for you to add your `$("#formattingSection div img")` code. Here's what it would look like:

```
$('#loadSmileys').click(function() {
    $('#formattingSection').get ({
       url: "formattingdoc.html",
       success: success
    });
});

function success() {
    $('#formattingSection div img').click(function() {
        var code = $(this).attr("title");
            alert (code);
            $('wallpost').val($('wallpost').val() + code);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see where using a callback like this can come in really handy!

Comment: Callbacks come up a lot in javascript in general. If you ever get the chance to work with Node.Js, I highly suggest it. Learning it will give you a lot better understanding of how javascript works in general, and will get you used to the whole callback design philosophy and styles. But @khanh-to has a better solution - it's faster and less complex. His design relies on how the DOM tree operates in evaluating events, and thus, code/executing functions, leading to a better design in the end for the desired solution. Again, I really suggest Node.Js. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#formattingSection').load ('formattingdoc.html #formatting', function( response, status, xhr ) {
    loading_completed();
});
function loading_completed()
{
$('#formattingSection div img').click(function() {
    var code = $(this).attr("title");
    alert (code);
    $('wallpost').val($('wallpost').val() + code);
});

}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#loadSmileys').click(function() {
    $('#formattingSection').load ('formattingdoc.html #smileys', function() {
        $('#formattingSection div img').click(function() {
            var code = $(this).attr("title");
            alert (code);
            $('wallpost').val($('wallpost').val() + code);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 'on' method. This can apply click handlers to elements created after the on method is called.

e.g.

```
$("#formattingSection").on("click","div img",function() {
    ...
}
```

As imges are added, they will automatically get the click handler functionality.

This question I asked helps explain the difference:  [jquery use of bind vs on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658231/jquery-use-of-bind-vs-on-click)