# Add Div's on Click with counter & limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add some functionality with the below code that only 5 times one can click the add button.

Also I would like to add a delete button with every replicated so when clicked, div is deleted and the counter of the 5 times is decreased.

HTML:

```
    <button id="button" onlick="duplicate()">Add another plan</button>
<div id="duplicater">
    <p>Choose Your Mobile Plan</p>
    <select>
        <option value="1">Package 1</option>
        <option value="2">Package 2</option>
        <option value="3">Package 3</option>
        <option value="4">Package 4</option>
        <option value="5">Package 5</option>
        <option value="6">Package 6</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;

var i = 0; var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

function duplicate() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "duplicater" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone); }
```

A JSFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/7x4re/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a button to delete the element like this:

```
<button id="button">Add another plan</button>
<div id="duplicater">
<p>Choose Your Mobile Plan</p>
<select>
    <option value="1">Package 1</option>
    <option value="2">Package 2</option>
    <option value="3">Package 3</option>
    <option value="4">Package 4</option>
    <option value="5">Package 5</option>
    <option value="6">Package 6</option>
</select>
    <button class='removebutton'>Delete</button>
</div>
```

You can enable a function to fire when it's clicked using jquery:

```
$('body').on('click', ".removebutton", remove);
```

Finally, the remove handler can remove the clicked element:

```
function remove() {
if (count > 1) {
    if ($(this).parent().attr('id') != 'duplicater') {
        $(this).parent().remove();
        count--;
    } else {
        alert("You can't delete the first plan");
    }
} else {
    alert("You can't delete the first plan");
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JVzCt/

I've used a similar approach to the counter as used by ReeCube.

As this uses jquery, you need to include it, either from your local machine or from somewhere else e.g.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

All the js code should be wrapped in the standard jquery ready function:

```
$(function(){
    // Put your js code here.
});
```

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with the jquery 'on' method used, one of my previous questions may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658231/jquery-use-of-bind-vs-on-click

Comment: For some reason when I am trying to run the JSFIDDLE code locally on my machine it is not working :/ do you have an idea why is that ?

Comment: Have you included jquery ?

Comment: Yes I did, I included the following:  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

Comment: Chrome is giving me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Comment: When does that error occur ? On load, or when you click something ?

Comment: Its happening on load. I load up the file and when I try clicking obviously nothing is happening.

Comment: Thanks, that could be it. Updated answer to show how.

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks SteveP everything is working. I will continue adding to my code to make t functional for the last result will repost if I get stuck.

Comment: No problem. Also, I liked Roko's answer if you just want one remove button at the top.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to **add an if before your duplicate code**:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;

var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

var i = 1;

function duplicate() {
    if (i < 6) {
        var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
        clone.id = "duplicater" + i++; // there can only be one element with an ID
        original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    }
}
```

[1. Example on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7x4re/3/)

If you want to **disable the button when 5 times clicked**, below is the code:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;

var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');

var i = 1;
var max = 5;

function duplicate() {
    if (i < max + 1) {
        var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
        clone.id = "duplicater" + i++; // there can only be one element with an ID
        original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
        if (i > max) document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

[2. And an example on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7x4re/4/)

[**3. Finally the master solution with add and remove button. But just in a JSFiddle because the code is large...**](http://jsfiddle.net/7x4re/6/)

[4. I know it's already a lot but I improved all this, here is the JSFiddle with add and remove button, disable enable function, min max variable and without any i or count varaible, so it's the ultimate master solution ;)](http://jsfiddle.net/7x4re/7/)

Comment: This is working perfectly, however I need to add a delete button on every duplicate. If for example 5 is reached and a delete is pressed, a div gets deleted and the button gets re-enabled

Comment: the solutions 3. and 4. contain the add and remove button

Comment: Many thanks ReeCube your solution is also working perfectly fine.