# Javascript Clone and Loop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I have a `<div>` which I clone(duplicate) and also I have set it in *a loop* to be duplicated till a particular limit.

Loop doesn't work, any issue with my loop ?

Here's my <kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3L05as1n)</kbd>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3L05as1n/2/

Comment: It works but have you checked how many times it clones ? I have set it to be cloned 3 times

Comment: yes, i checking it right now. you didn't reset i to 0 after or before while

Comment: OK, How can I set a limit please help.

Comment: @Vinayak this might help you [**Stackoverflow Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22456609/4763084)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `var clone = original.cloneNode(true);` inside the `while` loop.

This is the result:

```js
document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;
var i = 0;
var counter4 = 3;
var original = document.getElementById('duplicate');

function duplicate() {
    while (i < counter4){
        var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
        console.log(clone)
        clone.id = "duplicate"; // there can only be one element with an ID
        original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
        i++;
    }      
}
```

```css
#duplicate{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button" value="Button">
    <div id="duplicate">
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this too but I want to shopup one by one not all at a time.

Comment: What dou you mean 'shopup one by one'?
if you not create the clone every time you iterate, you only have one cloned item. That's why the clone only shows once.