# Unwanted event handler function is executing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events, eventhandler

I'm new to jQuery and I've some problem of redundant execution of an event handler. Here is my code:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'ctrl+c', function(){
    console.log("Something is wrong!!!");
});
```

I'm not pressing, Ctrl+C at all, but my console is printing the message as many times as I'm pressing any key. What's the flaw here? Thanks in advance, for any assistance.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658231/jquery-use-of-bind-vs-on-click helps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're binding the event to ANY `keydown`. You want to use the `keydown` event, but then check to make sure that your specified keys are the ones being pressed. `e.ctrlKey` will check for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and you can use `e.which` to compare the other key, which in this case would be <kbd>C</kbd>

Here's a full example

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
  console.log('some key pressed');
  if (String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase() == "c" && e.ctrlKey) {
    alert('ctrl+C pressed');
  }
});
```

Comment: note jQuery normalizes cross browser key codes into `e.which`

Comment: I know this one, but what is e.ctrlkey specifying?

Comment: Okay, I've got it all. Thanks

Comment: But the function still executing more than one time (3 times) on one event.

Comment: Maybe you want to use `keyup` instead?

Answer (score 2):

[According to the API](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), you're passing `'ctrl+c'` to the event handler as event data, which means that the callback will execute on every `keydown` event and you're not making use of the `'ctrl+c'` data you passed in to do any key checking.

If, instead, what you want is to detect when a key is pressed in combination with `ctrl` you'll need to check the `which` and `ctrlKey` properties of the event object:

```
...keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which === yourkeycode && e.ctrlKey) {
        ...do stuff...
    }
});
```

Comment: Okay, that clarifies everything. THanks

Answer (score 1):

Andrew's answer is correct, however JQuery offers binding to copy/paste/cut actions directly, which is cleaner.

```
$(document).bind('copy', function() {
  alert('ctrl+C pressed');
});
```